# Error handling in a stored procedure in oracle sql failed

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am inserting into a table in oracle SQL using a stored procedure and I want to raise an error if the number of the health record that I am creating already exists, not allowing to insert the values in the table. This is the code:

```
BEGIN
SELECT MAHDAR_NUM INTO L_MAHDAR_NUM FROM MEDICALPST.mahdar WHERE MAHDAR_NUM=i.MAHDAR_NUM;
exception when others then
P_MSG:=NULL;
END;

IF L_MAHDAR_NUM IS NOT NULL
THEN
P_MSG:=006;
ROLLBACK;
END IF;

IF P_MSG IS NULL
THEN
INSERT INTO medicalpst.mahdar 
VALUES (L_MAHDAR_SEQ,
        L_DECISION_SEQ,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
       ...
```

However, when I insert a `MAHDAR_NUM` that already exists, it is not raising an error and it is inserting the values in the table anyways.
I would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you're doing it wrong.

There should be a primary (or unique) key on `MADHAR_NUM` column which would prevent duplicates to be entered. What's good in it? Database takes care about duplicates, you don't have to do anything (unless you want). In that case, code would be as simple as

```
begin
  insert into madhar (col1, col2, col3, ...)
    values (l_madhar_seq, l_decision_seq, null, ...);
exception
  when dup_val_on_index then 
    null;
end;
```

(I don't know where `l_madhar_seq, l_decision_seq` come from, but - according to their names, they look like locally declared variables. You should know).

---

If, for some reason, you don't want to let database handle duplicates for you, consider something like this:

```
declare
  l_madhar_num madhar.madhar_num%type;
begin
  for i in (select madhar_num, ... from some_table where some_conditions) loop
    begin
      -- if this SELECT returns a value, nothing will happen as no commands
      -- follow the SELECT
      select madhar_num
        into l_madhar_num
        from madhar
        where madhar_num = i.madhar_num;
    exception
      -- but, if that SELECT returns nothing, NO_DATA_FOUND will be raised
      -- which means that you should insert a new row into a table.
      when no_data_found then
        insert into madhar (col1, col2, col3, ...)
        values (l_madhar_seq, l_decision_seq, null, ...);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I already have another primary key, which is l_mahdar_seq, so is there any other method, or any problem in my code? @Littlefoot

Comment: As of "any problem with your code" - I edited my answer and suggested what you might try to do. See if it helps.